# How to coarsen ordered 1D data into irregular bins with Python

Tags: python, scipy, binning

I have a high frequency set of ordered 1D data set that relates to observations of a property with respect to depth, consisting of a continuous float value observation versus monotonically increasing depth

I'd like to find a way to coarsen this data set up into user defined number of contiguous bins (or zones), each of which is described by a single mean value and lower depth limit (the top depth limit being defined by the end of the zone above it). The criteria for splitting the zones should be k-means like - in that (within the bounds of the number of zones specified) there will be minimum property variance within each zone and maximum variation between adjacent zones.

As an example, if I had a small high frequency dataset as follows;

```
depth = [2920.530612, 2920.653061, 2920.734694, 2920.857143, 2920.938776, 2921.102041, 2921.22449, 2921.346939, 2921.469388, 2921.510204, 2921.55, 2921.632653, 2921.795918, 2922, 2922.081633, 2922.122449, 2922.244898, 2922.326531, 2922.489796, 2922.612245, 2922.857143, 2922.979592, 2923.020408, 2923.142857, 2923.265306]
value = [0.0098299, 0.009827939, 0.009826632, 1004.042327, 3696.000306, 3943.831644, 3038.254723, 3693.543377, 3692.806616, 50.04989348, 15.0127, 2665.2111, 3690.842641, 3238.749497, 429.4979635, 18.81228993, 1800.889643, 2662.199897, 3454.082382, 3934.140146, 3030.184014, 0.556587319, 8.593768956, 11.90163067, 26.01012696]
```

And I was to request a split into 7 zones, it would return something like the following;

```
depth_7zone =[2920.530612, 2920.857143, 2920.857143, 2921.510204, 2921.510204, 2921.632653, 2921.632653, 2922.081633, 2922.081633, 2922.244898, 2922.244898, 2922.979592, 2922.979592, 2923.265306]
value_7zone = [0.009828157, 0.009828157, 3178.079832, 3178.079832, 32.53129674, 32.53129674, 3198.267746, 3198.267746, 224.1551267, 224.1551267, 2976.299216, 2976.299216, 11.76552848, 11.76552848]
```

which can be visualized as (blue = original data, red = data split into 7 zones);

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

plt.plot(value, depth, '-o')
plt.plot(value_7zone, depth_7zone, '-', color='red')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Depth')
plt.show()
```

[image: Original data with zonated (in red) data]

I've tried standard k-means clustering, and it doesn't appear suited to this ordered 1D problem. I was thinking of methods perhaps used for digital signal processing but all I could find discretize into constant bin sizes, or even for image compression but that may be overkill and likely expect 2D data

Can anyone suggest an avenue to explore further? (I'm fairly new to Python so apologies in advance)